# How to add meta tag to the topmost iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I've a webapp which needs to be published into a website. It has many iFrames like hierarchy of iFrames. It has 10 or so levels of iFrame and inside one of them my webapp is loaded. The website loads my webapp in QUIRKS mode for some IE9 browsers(yes we need IE9 browser support as per the client requirement). I tried using top.window object to add the IE Edge meta tag but it did not work. Is there any way to accomplish this or I need to deal with QUIRKS mode ? The problem is with layout of webapp in the QUIRKS mode as it's very hard to figure out which element layout is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the topmost frame does not share the same domain, you won't be able to communicate with it. It's part of the **"same-origin policy"**